# How to optimize this path algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, nodes

There are N nodes (n1, ... nn), nodes are bidirectional, and each node can be connected to 0 or more nodes. Nodes in the connection have attenuation (0 - 1). Now we need to calculate the cumulative attenuation from node M to node N, and the maximum value of attenuation is 1

Maybe the text is hard to understand, so I drew a diagram
[image]

The current algorithm is to enumerate all paths, but it is slow.

I expect it to be more efficient.

Comment: This doesn't look like a realistic problem. What is the context?

Comment: @noodle_run – 
Why do you consider only the two paths PathI and PathN, not any path with the connection between n3 and the unnumbered node below?

Comment: @Armali Sorry, I have used the algebra of "N", I think everyone can understand that there are "an unknown number of paths".

Answer (score 3):

I think you made a mistake in your image -- you probably want max product instead of min product, i.e., the least attenuated path.  Anyway...

Convert each attenuation *a* to *-log(a)*.  Now you can add them together instead of multiplying, and your problem becomes a common shortest-path problem.

You can use [Dijkstra's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).